# Symfony2 Annotation Inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

In my project, I have a BaseController class which implements several methods used by all of my controllers.

Now I wanted to add @QueryParam for that base class. My class looks like this:

```
class DoctrineRESTQueryController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @QueryParam(name="start",default=0)
     * @QueryParam(name="limit",default=null)
     */
    public function getQueryResponseAction (ParamFetcher $paramFetcher) {

    }
}
```

Now I have my actual controller which extends from my base controller:

```
class DefaultController extends DoctrineRESTQueryController {

    /**
     * Retrieves all SI Prefixes in the database
     *
     * @Routing\Route("/siprefix", defaults={"method" = "get","_format" = "json"})
     * @Routing\Method({"GET"})
     * @ApiDoc(output="array<PartKeepr\SiPrefixBundle\Entity\SiPrefix>")
     *
     * @View()
     *
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getQueryResponseAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher) {
         $paramFetcher->get("start");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, Symfony2 doesn't seem to inherit the @QueryParam annotations from the superclass, because the call to $paramFetcher->get("start") results in an exception "No @QueryParam/@RequestParam configuration for parameter 'start'".

Is there any way to make annotation inheritance work, or any other solution so I don't have to add @QueryParam to each of my controllers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no feature in `FosRestBundle` for this, so you must override parts of it for what you need, more specifically the method `getParamsFromMethod` in class `FOSRestBundle/Request/ParamReader` (see [source code here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/19575ef7ff64a3e58dad813a58012dde14994b40/Request/ParamReader.php#L75)).

This can be done through bundle inheritance.

First, subclass `FOSRestBundle\Request\ParamReader` in one of your bundles, e.g. `YourSite\RestBundle\Request\MyParamReader` and override `getParamsFromMethod` by loading the annotations of the parent method and merging them with those of the current one:

```
namespace YourSite\RestBundle\Request\MyParamReader;

use FOSRestBundle\Request\ParamReader;

class MyParamReader extends ParamReader
{
    public function getParamsFromMethod(\ReflectionMethod $method)
    {
        $parentParams = array();
        $params = parent::getParamsFromMethod($method);

        // This loads the annotations of the parent method
        $declaringClass = $method->getDeclaringClass();
        $parentClass = $declaringClass->getParentClass();

        if ($parentClass && $parentClass->hasMethod($method->getShortName())) {
            $parentMethod = $parentClass->getMethod($method->getShortName());
            $parentParams = parent::getParamsFromMethod($parentMethod);
        }

        return array_merge($params, $parentParams);
    }
}
```

You can modify the code to handle deep inheritance hierarchies, if necessary.

Now you should tell `FOSRestBundle` to use your `YourSite\RestBundle\Request\MyParamReader` class instead of `FOSRestBundle\Request\ParamReader`. You need to override the service definition, where the parameter reader is listed as a dependency. This is where bundle overriding/inheritance comes into play, see [this Symfony2 article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html).

The service definition is located in the `Resources/config/request.xml` file (see [source  code here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/e3a28ebf74724a51a31d6142b002c0c9652f71a4/Resources/config/request.xml)), `FOSRestBundle\Request\ParamReader` is a dependency of `FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcher`.

So you must override the `Resources/config/request.xml` file. To do this, following the above article, register your bundle and declare `FOSRestBundle` as its parent:

```
namespace YourSite\RestBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class YourSiteRestBundle extends Bundle
{
     public function getParent()
     {
          return 'FOSRestBundle';
     }
}
```

Create file `YourSite\RestBundle\Resources\config\request.xml` to add `YourSite\RestBundle\Request\MyParamReader` as a dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <parameters>
        <parameter key="fos_rest.request.param_fetcher.class">FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcher</parameter>
        <parameter key="your_site_rest.request.param_fetcher.reader.class">YourSite\RestBundle\Request\MyParamReader</parameter>
    </parameters>
    <services>
        <service id="fos_rest.request.param_fetcher" class="%fos_rest.request.param_fetcher.class%" scope="request">
            <argument type="service" id="your_site.request.param_fetcher.reader"/>
            <argument type="service" id="request"/>
            <argument type="service" id="fos_rest.violation_formatter"/>
            <argument type="service" id="validator" on-invalid="null"/>
        </service>
        <service id="your_site.request.param_fetcher.reader" class="%your_site_rest.request.param_fetcher.reader.class%">
            <argument type="service" id="annotation_reader"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

This is untested, but it should work.

Comment: You're amazing! One little bugfix:

The custom reader should check if the parent method actually exists:

        if ($parentClass && $parentClass->hasMethod($method->getShortName())) {
            $parentMethod = $parentClass->getMethod($method->getShortName());
            $parentParams = parent::getParamsFromMethod($parentMethod);
        }

        return array_merge($params, $parentParams);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Great solution, thanks! Maybe someone looking for same .yml configuration in symfony3, the following should works:

```
parameters:
    fos_rest.request.param_fetcher.class: FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcher
    your_site_rest.request.param_fetcher.reader.class: YourSiteBundle\Request\MyParamReader

services:
    fos_rest.request.param_fetcher:
        class: %fos_rest.request.param_fetcher.class%
        arguments: ['@service_container', '@your_site.request.param_fetcher.reader', '@request_stack', '@?validator']
        scope: request
    your_site.request.param_fetcher.reader:
        class: %your_site.request.param_fetcher.reader.class%
        arguments: ['@annotation_reader']
```